# No debugger in the TypeScript

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have next problem. I am create project in a visual studio 2017. 
https://yadi.sk/i/D-V8v3U5WN025Q
I am add in the project next the file, which contains the class and function “Bitrix.connect()”.
https://yadi.sk/i/5vb4IB3-XvSycA
I use the debug and put a stop point here.
https://yadi.sk/i/tbrw3uSl0m4lpw
I am stopping here if run debug.
https://yadi.sk/i/CvIPzFNC9CVQog
But if I put a stop point in the Bitrix.connect(), I am not stop on the this point.
https://yadi.sk/i/lwgnkOV8vGAT0Q
The point has a transparent center.
If I am press F11 and debugger put in the Bitrix.connect().
https://yadi.sk/i/yaG_AqGL1R0TBQ
But if I press F5, I do not stop in the point stop.
I can stop on the point with help key F10 or F11.
I don't know why visual studio works like this.
Help me please.
https://yadi.sk/d/W4hJqbRkDz5HvQ

Comment: Welcome, your question is very hard to understand, maybe you should first visit the Stack Overflow Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour Afterwards it will be easier for you to understand how this community works.

Comment: Hi friend, I tried to follow your steps and can reproduced this issue in VS 2017. But in VS code, the same solution, it works fine and the breakpoint inside the Bitrix.connect() be hit by F5. To workaround this issue in VS 2017, we can press F5, then disable and enable this specific breakpoint, press F5 again, this breakpoint should be hit.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Eclipse, you may use: TypEcs (http://typecsdev.com/).